# ‘memcopy’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, cstring

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>



using namespace std;
void printArray(int* arr, int size) {
    cout  << "Printing the array..." << endl;
    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++) {
        cout << arr[index] << endl;
    }
}

void populateArray(int* arr, int size) {
    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++) {
        arr[index] = index * 10 + 1;
    }
}

int main() {
    int size = 2;
    int* arr = new int[size];   
    populateArray(arr, size);
    size_t newSize = size * 2;
    int* newArr = new int[newSize];
    memcopy(newArr, arr, size);
    populateArray(newArr, newSize);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Even after including `cstring` , I am getting 'VarArr.cpp:25:27: error: ‘memcopy’ was not declared in this scope' error while compiling. What am I missing here ?

Comment: When C was created they couldn't use long names: you'll need to remove the `o` from `memcopy()`.

Comment: did you mean `memcpy`?

Comment: Screw me up. That was the error . Bit embarrassing. C/C++ is rusty after a long time of java programming

Comment: If your compiler is smart enough, it'll tell you. `error: use of undeclared identifier 'memcopy'; did you mean 'memcpy'?`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct name is `memcpy`, not `memcopy`.

Answer (score 4):

You made a typo and meant to use `memcpy`, but you should prefer to use the C++ facilities instead.

```
std::copy(arr, arr + size, newArr);
```

You seem to be forgetting to delete your new'd arrays, which isn't a problem since the program ends right there, but it's a good habit to remember to do this.

Let the standard library manage your memory for you. Use a container like `std::vector` or a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Getting back to C++ after a long time. Just checking it with raw arrays rather going with vectors. But std::copy is a learning

Comment: This answer is better than @jefffrey's.